# How much memory should playwright take?

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I have a node app that uses playwright to scrape urls. It is hosted on heroku and when I call the function with the playwright instantiation, I almost immediately pushes the app over the 512MB memory limit. Is this expected just for basic usage of playwright?